# guard+rspec+spork always load all gems in bundle result quite slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, spork, guard

after my setup , everything is perfect except one thing.

spork always load all gem in bundle for each trigger of rspec run, this result quite slow .

how to avoid this? or is this a bug?

maybe caused by this error:

how to make DRB server run , should i point to as 127.0.0.1?

No DRb server is running. Running in local process instead ...

Comment: Can you paste your spork configuration file ?

Answer (score 1):

the line

```
No DRb server is running. Running in local process instead ...
```

tells you already that spork is not running correctly.
Try to run spork manually first and check if it helps (guess this is what the person before wanted to say).

If it works check your Guardfile for your spork setup.
You may have to run

```
guard init spork
```

in order to bootstrap the config for spork

Answer (score 0):

try to start up spork manually with "bundle exec spork" in other terminal.